# How to block / lessen EM-radiation/signal from home Wi-Fi router?

Tags: electromagnetism, wifi, electromagnetic, microwave, radiation

1) What materials and how can I use to *completely block* radiation from two antennas of my WiFi router?

2) What materials and how can I *lessen by 20-50%* radiation/signal from the third router antenna?

3) Is there a simple (household / amateur) way to verify intensity of router radiation - like neon bulb lighting close to electricity wires?

a) If I just wrap the antenna with metallized foil - would it work for sure?

b) How is it the usual way - those visible antennas are the only transmitters or there are additional transmitters (emitters) inside the casing?

I have a Wi-Fi router with three antennas. It says 2.4 GHz / 5 GHz. 2.4 is always blinking and 5 is always on (but not blinking).

I am concerned with electromagetic radiation and I would like to decreese it (the router shall still be switched on and shall continue to provide Wi-final signal).

Currently I do not have access to router menu.

P.S. This is not a question (or discussion) of "I am afraid of EM-radiation" - I am not.

I am asking a specific technical question and expect the answer to be a specific technical one.

I conjecture that just wrapping foil around antenna can actually increase (not decrease) signal. I cannot make 100% metal cage around.

Here is [Tom's Guide on foil reflector](https://www.tomsguide.com/us/aluminum-foil-wi-fi-extension,news-26097.html) (different topic, but related).

Comment: Just unplug it and use wired connections if you are afraid of the electromagnetic radiation. Reducing it by 50% is like putting the router a little bit further. Also don't use 50/60 Hz main supply/cell phones/microwave/.. All sources of radiation.

Comment: Placing the router in a metal box (a Faraday cage, Google that!) will prevent all EM waves from escaping that box. Why would you want to do this? The purpose of a WiFi router is to emit WiFi signals. Blocking them is like asking you to answer my questions but taping your mouth shut. If you're concerned about "radiation" then **don't use WiFi!**. Not going into the discussion that people mentioning that they're afraid of "WiFi radiation" don't fully understand radiation. Gamma radiation: very dangerous, WiFi signals: not so much as not ionizing and the dosage is also very small.

Comment: *I am concerned with electromagetic radiation* and also *This is not a question (or discussion) of "I am afraid of EM-radiation" - I am not.* Looks like a contradiction to me. But anyway. Place some **electric conductive** material between you and the router like a metal plate. Routers can change their power level depending on how well their signal is received so in the end, **whatever you do to attenuate the signal might not have the intended effect**. As WiFi uses quite low power levels, best would be to simply not be concerned. Would I be concerned with a WiFi router on my desk: no.

Comment: Many or most decent WiFi routers allow you to adjust power levels. If you “do not have access to router menu”, and the router is yours, contact the manufacturer or buy a new one.  If the router is not yours, you probably shouldn’t be tampering with it.

Comment: Blocking the signal from the router also means blocking the signal **to** the router.  Your other devices will have to transmit with higher power for your router to be able to "hear" them.  That means the device right there in front of you is transmitting with higher power.  That kind of misses your goal of having less RF flying about.  Modern wifi regulates its own transmit power to use as little power as needed.  If you monkey with it, you'll just make it have to transmit more power to make up for your blocking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unscrew each antenna. See what type of connector they use (most likely a SMA connector). If the router doesn't have removable antennas, you can also try taking the case off - perhaps there will be connectors inside the case, or perhaps you can remove them by force. I am not responsible for damage to your router.

> 1) What materials and how can I use to completely block radiation from two antennas of my WiFi router?

Most likely, you can simply remove the antenna and the router will not be able to radiate energy. The router will still try to transmit; the transmitted power will be reflected back into the transmitter circuit. There is a remote possibility that this could damage the transmitter (however this is mostly a problem for high-power transmitters, like radio station transmitters, which a Wi-Fi router is not).

If you want a slightly more robust solution, you can connect a *dummy load* to the antenna port. This is a resistor with the same impedance as the antenna. Antennas are typically 50Ω impedance ([source](https://superuser.com/questions/1033275/is-it-possible-to-extend-the-antenna-for-wireless-router-over-coax)) so you will need a 50Ω dummy load with the right connector. The dummy load "looks like" an antenna electrically, but it doesn't actually radiate or receive any signal.

> 2) What materials and how can I lessen by 20-50% radiation/signal from the third router antenna?

The proper way to do this would be with an *attenuator*, which is like a dummy load but with two connectors. One side plugs into the router and the other side plugs into the antenna.

This is the electrical engineering way to reduce the power of an RF signal.

> 3) Is there a simple (household / amateur) way to verify intensity of router radiation - like neon bulb lighting close to electricity wires?

You are looking for a [field strength meter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_strength_meter). Shopping recommendations are [off-topic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site.

> a) If I just wrap the antenna with metallized foil - would it work for sure?

Not necessarily, but you could try it. I would imagine that since your foil wrapping is antenna-shaped, and very close to the antenna, the signal *might* couple to your foil wrapping and then be radiated by the foil. However, I am not sure.

If you connect the foil to the ground on the antenna connector, then you've made an approximation of coax cable, which does provide shielding. But why not just disconnect the antenna?

> b) How is it the usual way - those visible antennas are the only transmitters or there are additional transmitters (emitters) inside the casing?

Generally, for a Wi-Fi router, the only antennas are the ones you can see.

Note: the word "transmitter" usually refers to the circuit that produces the radio signal, or the whole device, not just the antenna. Of course the circuit is inside the casing.

Comment: "_Unscrew each antenna. […] I am not responsible for damage to your router._" Does it necessarily damage the transmitter?